# Como quitar el borde cuando pongo un fondo?

Tags: html, css, imagen

Estoy creando una pagína, pero cuando agrego el fondo de la pagina me aparece una franja o borde blanco en la parte superior, ya probé con "display: block, flex, etc" en general soluciones que me aparecieron pero al final no me dio ninguna y no se como solucionarlo :(
........................................................................................................................................................................................
Asi es como se ve cuando inserto la imagen, hasta el propio navbar baja y no se por que...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Carter+One&family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400;700&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@100&display=swap');

/* Css general */

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,.7),rgba(4,9,30,.7)),url(imagenes/fondo-gris.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}


/* Css navbar */

.nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

.navbar-mid{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 30px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-mid ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-mid ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Drewki</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="">drewki._</a>
            <div class="navbar-mid">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">// inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">// sobre mi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">// trabajos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quita el margin que tienes puesto en **.nav**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tu clase .nav tienes un margin

```
.nav{
  //etc
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Este margen de 20px está en todos los sentidos (arriba, abajo, izquierda y derecha). El margin superior empuja tu contenido hacia abajo dejando algo vacío arriba

tienes 2 soluciones faciles:

1. Cambiar el margin por padding

```
.nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

2. Mover el fondo a la etiqueta Body

```
body{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,.7),rgba(4,9,30,.7)),url(imagenes/fondo-gris.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el margin que tienes en .nav

Debes remplazar esto:

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Por esto:

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

En este caso si tu intención es separar el Nav de la parte superior del  header y deseas que este esté dentro del mismo, podrías aplicar un padding-top al header como opción.

Quedando header de esta manera en css:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7), rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7)),
    url(imagenes/fondo-gris.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Otra opción podría ser poner el padding-top al .nav, pero recuerda que el padding agrega espacio desde el borde del elemento hacia adentro, entonces si lo aplicas al .nav, quedará más espacio dentro del .nav arriba que abajo.. Si se aplica el padding al header lo que hará será agregar un espacio entre el borde superior del header y el navbar, y este navbar quedará sin modificaciones.